# How to round numbers of a data frame in R preserving the sum?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame in R:

```
df <- structure(list(code = c(3500105, 3500105, 3500105, 3500105, 3500105, 3500105), 
                     type = c("var11", "var21", "var22", "var23", "var24", "var31"), 
                     adequate = c(6737.44433328298, 11620.2844916867, 11324.2844916867, 11246.4427150112, 11324.2844916867, 11228.5578085444), 
                     inadequate = c(545.01978642828, 10.7155083133282, 10.7155083133282, 77.841776675461, 0, 95.7266831422943), 
                     missing = c(4348.53588028873, NA, 296, 306.715508313328, 306.715508313328, 306.715508313328), 
                     total = c(11631, 11631, 11631, 11631, 11631, 11631)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Before exporting this data, I would like to round the numbers of the columns "adequate", "inadequate" and "missing". The problem is that the sum of the rounded numbers for every line must be equal to the sum of the numbers before rounding them (which is equal to the "total" column).

I have found a function that could help me with this issue:

```
round preserve_sum <- function(x) {
  y <- floor(x)
  indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))
  y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
  y
}
```

How to apply this function to every line of the dataset?

Comment: Is this giving you the expected output: `df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(adequate, inadequate), ~ round(., 0)) %>%
 mutate(missing = total - (adequate + inadequate))`?

Comment: The simple round function does not give the expected output for the entire data frame

Comment: Is the `round_preserve_sum` function even working alone? What is `up`?

Comment: I have fixed the round_preserve_sum function