# How to implement a function using multiple columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This question was previously asked: [How to round numbers of a data frame in R preserving the sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476799/how-to-round-numbers-of-a-data-frame-in-r-preserving-the-sum)

I also want to implement this function in dplyr that rounds and preserves unity depending on number of digits wanted:

```
round_preserve_sum <- function(x, digits = 0) {
  up <- 10 ^ digits
  x <- x * up
  y <- floor(x)
  indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))
  y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
  y / up
}
```

Here is a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(SAND = c(0.00000, 28.00000, 27.27273),
                 SILT = c(45.45455, 35.00000, 34.34343),
                 CLAY = c(54.54545, 37.00000, 38.38384))
```

Using this function with these values separately, I get:

```
round_preserve_sum(c(0.00000, 45.45455, 54.54545), 0)
```

[1]  0 45 55

```
 round_preserve_sum(c(28.00000, 35.00000, 37.00000), 0)
```

[1] 28 35 37

```
 round_preserve_sum(c(27.27273, 34.34343, 38.38384), 0)
```

[1] 27 34 39

which all sum to a 100

When I implement this function in dplyr :

```
df.Rd0 <-df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(SAND, SILT, CLAY), ~round_preserve_sum(.,0)),
         Sum = SAND + SILT + CLAY)
```

I get :

```
   SAND SILT CLAY  Sum 
1    0   46   55   101 
2   28   35   37   100 
3   27   34   38    99
```

Not using tilde:

```
df.Rd0 <-df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(SAND, SILT, CLAY), round_preserve_sum(.,0)),
         Sum = SAND + SILT + CLAY)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error : Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(c(SAND, SILT, CLAY), round_preserve_sum(., 0))`.
x undefined columns selected
```

I guess the function is not programmed for vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~` is a lambda expression i.e. short form for `function(.x)`.  If we don't use it, then specify the format parameters as named one

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(SAND, SILT, CLAY), round_preserve_sum, digits = 0),
         Sum = SAND + SILT + CLAY)
```

-output

```
  SAND SILT CLAY Sum
1    0   46   55 101
2   28   35   37 100
3   27   34   38  99
```

---

Regarding the OP's manual use of getting sum as 100, it was `rowwise`, and not column wise - `across` loops over columns.  We need `rowwise` with `c_across`

```
df %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(Sum = sum(round_preserve_sum(c_across(everything()), 0))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   SAND  SILT  CLAY   Sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0    45.5  54.5   100
2  28    35    37     100
3  27.3  34.3  38.4   100
```

---

If we want to return the rounded columns along with sum, use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    pmap_dfr(~ {tmp <- round_preserve_sum(c(...), 0)
      c(tmp, Sum = sum(tmp))})
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   SAND  SILT  CLAY   Sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0    45    55   100
2    28    35    37   100
3    27    34    39   100
```

---

THis can be made faster with `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
df <- dapply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = round_preserve_sum, 0)
df$Sum <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the 2 solutions. I was trying out collapse and got this message:  `Error in aplyfun(.Call(Cpp_mrtl, do.call(cbind, X), FALSE, 0L), FUN, ...) : 
  la fonction 'Rcpp_precious_remove' n'existe pas dans le package 'Rcpp'`   I loaded Rcpp tried again and R bugged

Comment: Also with collapse:dapply, is there any way to specify which column or variable to apply function on. Didn't find it in the reference: [link]()https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/dapply.html)

Comment: Thanks again @akrun. Reinstalled Rcpp and works. Got it for specifiying columns in collapse :  get_vars(df, c("SAND", "SILT", "CLAY")) <- dapply(get_vars(df, c("SAND", "SILT", "CLAY")), FUN = round_preserve_sum, 0,  MARGIN = 1)
df$Sum2 <- rowSums(get_vars(df, c("SAND", "SILT", "CLAY")), na.rm = TRUE)  Haven't figured it out yet for purr:pmap_dfr

Comment: @Marc-OlivierGasser you meant you haven't tried `pmap`?

Comment: pmap seems to work. I just don't know how to specify colums. Also, I still have problems with get_vars in collapse. I want to apply function on specific columns, either change values or create new columns. Using across in dplyr was pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Marc-OlivierGasser with `pmap` you can use `df %>% select(yourcols) %>% pmap_dfr(~ {tmp <- round_preserve_sum(c(...), 0)
      c(tmp, Sum = sum(tmp))})` and then if there are more columns, bind with the rest